# Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в предложении с двумя основами?

Tags: запятые, спп

Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в предложении:

*Мы проверим как упаковывался заказ и свяжемся с Вами.*

Answer (score 2):

Тут нужны две запятые – обособляющие придаточное предложение.

Главное: *Мы проверим и свяжемся с Вами.* Придаточное найдите сами.